# Hibernate does not rollback natively generated ID after Hibernate Exception

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-4.x, hibernate3

> I have a method in my Transactional Service which validates an object and saves it. During this save assume that due to garbage data in the "child" object - a DataException is thrown.
>
> This being a RuntimeException, Hibernate triggers a rollback. This I verified from the logs as shown below.
>
> When I catch the exception in my Action I see that the "child" object in Session has an identifier associated with it. Why is this happening?
>
> This is causing a problem when the user corrects the value and tries to save the object again and hibernate tries to update the object throws a Batch update StaleStateException.
>
> I found a blog which describes the exact problem http://www.jroller.com/hasant/entry/hibernate_saveorupdate_trap_for_web . Is there a solution to this which I'm missing? Is using merge the way out? Will hibernate.use_identifier_rollback=true help?

### Code

```
public @Component("action") @Scope("prototype") class Action {
  private @Autowired Service service;
  public void save() {
    try {
      A parent = new A();
      B child = new B();
      child.setValue(2782375983275837583758375); // Data Truncation will be thrown
      service.save(parent, child);
    } catch(Exception e) {
      // Why does "child" have an id after rollback?
    }
  }
}

public @Service @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class) class ServiceImpl implements Service {
  private @Autowired GeneralDAO generalDao;

  public void save(A parent, B child) throws Exception {
    child.setParent(parent);
    removeExistingGrandChildren(child);
    child.setGrandChildren(new LinkedHashSet<C>());
    C grandChild = new C(something);
    generalDao.saveOrUpdate(child); // cascades and saves grandChildren also.
  }

  private void removeExistingGrandChildren(B child) throws Exception {
    if(child.getId() != null) {
      Collection<C> grandChildren = loadGrandChildren(child.getId());
      for(C grandChild : grandChildren) {
        generalDao.delete(grandChild);
      }
    }
  }
}

public @Repository("generalDao") class GeneralDAOImpl implements GeneralDao {
  private @Autowired SessionFactory sessionFactory;

  protected SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
  }

  protected void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
  }

  @Override
  public Object saveOrUpdate(Object bean) {
    Session session = getSession();
    session.saveOrUpdate(bean);
    return bean;
  }

  protected Session getSession() {
    Session currentSession = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    return currentSession;
  }
}
```

### Mappings

```
<class name="com.xxx.model.A" table="A">        
  <id name="id" type="java.lang.Integer" column="id">
    <generator class="native"></generator>
  </id>
  <set name="children" inverse="true" lazy="true" table="B" cascade="save-update">
    <key column="a_Id"/>
    <one-to-many class="com.xxx.model.B" />
  </set>
  <property name="p0" type="java.lang.Integer" column="p0" />
</class>

<class name="com.xxx.model.B" table="B">        
  <id name="id" type="java.lang.Integer" column="id">
    <generator class="native"></generator>
  </id>
  <many-to-one name="parent" class="com.xxx.model.A" fetch="join" lazy="false" column="a_Id" />
  <set name="grandchildren" inverse="true" lazy="true" table="C" cascade="save-update">
    <key column="b_Id"/>
    <one-to-many class="com.xxx.model.C" />
  </set>
  <property name="p1" type="java.lang.Integer" column="p1" />
</class>

<class name="com.xxx.model.C" table="C">        
  <id name="id" type="java.lang.Integer" column="id">
    <generator class="native"></generator>
  </id>
  <many-to-one name="child" class="com.xxx.model.B" fetch="join" lazy="false" column="b_Id" />
  <property name="p2" type="java.lang.Integer" column="p2" />
</class>
```

### Stack Trace

```
13:53:08,474 DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue  - Executing identity-insert immediately
13:53:08,474 DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL  - 
    insert into dbo.B(p1) values (?)
13:53:08,482 DEBUG org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGeneratorHelper  - Natively generated identity: 6581
13:53:08,483 DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue  - Executing identity-insert immediately
13:53:08,483 DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL  - 
    insert into dbo.C(p2) values (?)
13:53:08,487 DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper  - Data truncation [n/a]
java.sql.DataTruncation: Data truncation
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SQLDiagnostic.addDiagnostic(SQLDiagnostic.java:379)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.tdsErrorToken(TdsCore.java:2781)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.nextToken(TdsCore.java:2224)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.getMoreResults(TdsCore.java:628)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.processResults(JtdsStatement.java:525)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.executeSQL(JtdsStatement.java:487)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(JtdsPreparedStatement.java:421)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:233)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractProxyHandler.invoke(AbstractProxyHandler.java:81)
    at $Proxy42.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2936)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3447)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:362)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:203)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:183)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:320)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:287)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:193)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:204)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:114)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:727)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:719)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingAction$5.cascade(CascadingAction.java:258)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:383)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:326)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:412)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:353)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:329)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:165)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeAfterSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:448)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:293)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:193)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:204)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:114)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:727)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:719)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:715)
    at com.xxx.dao.GeneralDao.saveOrUpdate(GeneralDao.java:59)
    at com.xxx.service.ServiceImpl.save(ServiceImpl.java:727)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:319)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at $Proxy33.save(Unknown Source)
    at com.xxx.action.Action.save(Action.java:433)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:450)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:289)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:252)
    at com.xxx.interceptor.RequestInfoInterceptor.intercept(RequestInfoInterceptor.java:52)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:176)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:265)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:191)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:325)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:256)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:176)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:187)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:546)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:91)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.displaytag.filter.ResponseOverrideFilter.doFilter(ResponseOverrideFilter.java:125)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:399)
    at org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
    at org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:278)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilterHttp(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:101)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilterHttp(LogoutFilter.java:89)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411)
    at org.springframework.security.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilterHttp(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:235)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:188)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:931)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
13:53:08,502 WARN  org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper  - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 22001
13:53:08,502 ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper  - Data truncation
13:53:08,502 WARN  org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper  - SQL Error: 8115, SQLState: 22003
13:53:08,502 ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper  - Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric.
13:53:08,503 DEBUG org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager  - Initiating transaction rollback
13:53:08,504 DEBUG org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager  - Rolling back Hibernate transaction on Session [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[EntityKey[com.xxx.model.B#6581]],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=[] updates=[] deletions=[] collectionCreations=[] collectionRemovals=[] collectionUpdates=[] unresolvedInsertDependencies=UnresolvedEntityInsertActions[]])]
13:53:08,504 DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl  - rolling back
13:53:08,504 DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction  - rolled JDBC Connection
13:53:08,504 DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction  - re-enabling autocommit
13:53:08,505 DEBUG org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager  - Closing Hibernate Session [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[EntityKey[com.xxx.model.B#6581]],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=[] updates=[] deletions=[] collectionCreations=[] collectionRemovals=[] collectionUpdates=[] unresolvedInsertDependencies=UnresolvedEntityInsertActions[]])] after transaction
13:53:08,505 DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl  - Releasing JDBC connection
13:53:08,505 DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl  - Released JDBC connection
13:53:08,505 DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.ConnectionProxyHandler  - HHH000163: Logical connection releasing its physical connection
```

Comment: Thrown when a version number or timestamp check failed, indicating that the Session contained stale data (when using long transactions with versioning). Also occurs if we try delete or update a row that does not exist.

Note that this exception often indicates that the user failed to specify the correct unsaved-value strategy for a class!

[this](http://www.dil.univ-mrs.fr/~massat/docs/hibernate-3.1/api/org/hibernate/StaleStateException.html)

Comment: @Rat-a-tat-a-tat Ratatouille - Note: I am not asking why the StaleStateException occurred. I am asking as to why after the rollback the identifier is not removed which is leading to the StaleStateException. Secondly the id being an Integer should have unsaved-value as null by default.

Comment: Edited the Title for Clarity

Answer (score 0):

Check this answer to a similar question: [It's not a bug, but a feature](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67401366/4708779)

In summary, the process of generating ids is transactionless, so even if a rollback is issued, the generated ids does not get 'ungenerated'.

I have basically the same problem and I've tried setting `hibernate.use_identifier_rollback=true` but to no avail. The documentation for that property states that Hibernate will clear the id if the entity gets removed, which is not the case.

I've solved this by using `persist()` when I know it's a new entity, and `merge()` otherwise. Note that `persist()` will work even if your entity already has a generated id.